# How to customize the polar chart in this way?

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts 4.0.

This is what I get with the default parameters.

[image]

I want to customize it while I can't find the docs.

This is what I expect:

1. The background polygon can be filled at a specified color/transparency (eg. dark green in this picture)
2. The valued polygon can be filled at a specified color/transparency (eg. blue in this picture)
3. The value number can be displayed
4. The unwanted scale-number (0, 2.5, 5) can be hidden

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these options are described in the Highcharts-API-Doc: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

1) **The background polygon can be filled at a specified color/transparency (eg. dark green in this picture)**

This is tricky. You can either try to add a plotBand to the yAxis, but you need to know the max Value, otherwise it will leave a white gap. All the other options (set a background color to the pane or chart.plotBackgroundColor options do not take the shape of the polar chart into account.

```
yAxis: {
  plotBands: {
    from:0,
    to: 75000,
    color: '#0c0'
  }
}
```

2) **The valued polygon can be filled at a specified color/transparency (eg. blue in this picture)**

set the type of the series to 'area', you can then style it either directly in the series or via the plotOptions.series-Object

```
series: [{
  name: 'Whatever',
  type: 'area',
  data: [...]
}]

[...]

plotOptions: {
  area: {
    fillOpacity: 0.9
  }
}
```

3) **The value number can be displayed**

for areas, set the dataLabels.enabled property to true

```
plotOptions: {
  area: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
}
```

4) **The unwanted scale-number (0, 2.5, 5) can be hidden**

set the labels.enabled property of the yAxis to false

```
yAxis: {
  labels: {
    enabled: false
  }
}
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/doc_snyder/qnqux036/

Comment: Is it possible to format the datalables? In this case the 72, 95, 81? For instance, I want to make the bigger and red.

Comment: Yes, i cannot recomend the highcharts-api-doc enough: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.dataLabels

Comment: tthanks! Got it! Would you please take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/34272363/1661640