# How do I move the title-label of a polar (spider) graph with HighChart 4?

Tags: highcharts

I created a polar graph. It has some complicated title-lables. It looks as expected on desktop:

[image]

But when it's on mobile, the title-lables don't have enough room to show up. And HighCharts neither did it for me. So it looks like this:

[image]

What I desire is to move the two title-labels under the triangle, without changing how it behaves in Desktop view.

[image]

What can I do to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can translate labels using `tick.label.attr({ x: new_x });` method. For example, create some reposition method:

```
function reposition () {
    var chart = this,
        xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
        tick, bbox, xy;

  $.each(xAxis.tickPositions, function(i, pos){
    tick = xAxis.ticks[pos];

    if (tick && tick.label) {
      bbox = tick.label.getBBox(); // get label's bounding box
      xy = tick.label.xy;  // get label's xy position

      if (xy.x - bbox.width < 0) {
        tick.label.attr({
            x: bbox.width
        });
      }

      if (xy.x + bbox.width > chart.plotWidth + chart.plotLeft) {
        tick.label.attr({
            x: chart.plotWidth + chart.plotLeft - bbox.width
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Which will be called on each chart redraw and starting load events:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'line',
        events: {
            redraw: reposition,
          load: reposition
        }
    },
    ... 
 });
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wmgbbp9k/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y6gsgq8r/ When a label contains more lines, it'd be not perfect. Any solution for this?

Comment: In `tick.label.attr(...)` method, I'm changing only `x`. Feel free to calculate `y`and change that value when necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't know how to calculate. It's hard to get the desired offset. Would you please give me some hints?

Comment: Hmm.. how about using a bit different approach? Instead of trying to calculate position, set `labels.y = 0` so label will start/end always near the category corner? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/y6gsgq8r/1/

Comment: Thanks, this is a good workaround but not perfect because there is no padding/margin between the label and the graph

Comment: Ok, but id doesn't have to be `y = 0`, it can be also `y = 5` :) See: http://jsfiddle.net/y6gsgq8r/3/